# How to add information to BitVec variable and get that variable back with get_vars()?

Tags: z3py

In the code below I tried to add some extra information to `BitVec` variable, then created some condition, and then use `get_vars` to get back the `x` variable but it is always different because the output of this little snippet is `False`. I expected to be the same object but it seems that when `x > 3` is executed, `BoolRef` is created and `x` is lost. Also, I expected that `x.ast` would be the same as `var.ast` but the instances are different.

```
from z3 import BitVec
from z3.z3util import get_vars

x = BitVec('x', 256)
x.foo = 1

some_cond = x > 3

for var in get_vars(some_cond):
    print(var is x)
    print(hasattr(var, 'foo'))
```

I thought to wrap `z3.BitVec` function in a class that extends `z3.BitVecRef` but it will be a pain since I need to wrap all the other functions such as `z3.If`, `z3.And`, `z3.Or`, etc.

I can include information in the `name` of the `z3.BitVec` but it will be slower since I need to parse that string later.

So, my question is if there is any other way to add information to `z3.BitVec` and get that information later with or without `get_vars`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that as z3 processes these variables it "internalizes" them and converts them to `BitVecRef`'s; which no-longer produce true with the originals you had when you use the `is` construct.

Unfortunately, this is quite hard-coded in the way z3 and z3py works, so you cannot really work-around it. However, if you are *willing* to create and keep track of a list of variables yourself, then you can effectively simulate it like this:

```py
from z3 import BitVec, Or
from z3.z3util import get_vars

x = BitVec('x', 256)
x.foo = 1

y = BitVec('y', 256)
y.foo = 2

z = BitVec('z', 256)

some_cond = Or([x > 3, y < 1, z > 12])

def my_get_attribute(var, attrib, allMyVariables):
    for known in allMyVariables:
        if var == known:
           if hasattr(known, attrib):
              return getattr(known, attrib)
           else:
              raise Exception("Can't find attribute '{}' on variable '{}'".format(attrib, var))
    raise Exception("Can't find variable '{}', make sure allMyVariables is kept up-to-date.".format(var))

for var in get_vars(some_cond):
    print("var: {}, foo: {}".format(var, my_get_attribute(var, 'foo', [x, y, z])))
```

When I run this, I get:

```
var: x, foo: 1
var: y, foo: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("var: {}, foo: {}".format(var, my_get_attribute(var, 'foo', [x, y, z])))
  File "a.py", line 20, in my_get_attribute
    raise Exception("Can't find attribute '{}' on variable '{}'".format(attrib, var))
Exception: Can't find attribute 'foo' on variable 'z'
```

This isn't ideal as it requires you to keep track of your variables obviously; but I suspect you might already have that lying around if you are putting in attributes to start with. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are correct that `z3` "internalizes" `BitVec` to `BitVecRef`. But when I make some conditional, that condition will be about the `BitVecRef` instance, and I expect that `z3` keep track of all variables used in conditions and not create new ones when I call `get_vars`, maybe this will be slower than lookup to a table and retrieve the `BitVecRef` instance already created previously.

Comment: Unless you have millions of variables lying around, I wouldn't worry about performance. Perhaps you can use a dictionary instead of a list in `allMyVariables` if it becomes an issue. Are you seeing problems?

Comment: No. I keep track ``z3`` variables, maybe I can use your answer to get back those variables. I will make a performance test to check if it is the same as parse the name of the ``BitVec``. In my case, it will be O(n^2).